# Haskell Data.Map lookup AND delete at the same time

Tags: dictionary, haskell, lookup

I was recently using the `Map` type from `Data.Map` inside a State Monad and so I wanted to write a function, that looks up a value in the Map and also deletes it from the Map inside the State Monad.
My current implementation looks like this:

```
lookupDelete :: (Ord k) => k -> State (Map k v) (Maybe v)
lookupDelete k = do
    m <- get
    put (M.delete k m)
    return $ M.lookup k m
```

While this works, it feels quite inefficient. With mutable maps in imperative languages, it is not uncommon to find `delete` functions, that also return the value that was deleted.
I couldn't find a function for this, so I would really appreciate if someone knows one (or can explain why there is none)

Comment: `lookupDelete k = at k <<.= Nothing`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no function specifically for "delete and lookup". Instead you use a more general tool: [updateLookupWithKey](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:updateLookupWithKey) is "lookup and update", where update can be delete or modify.

```
updateLookupWithKey :: Ord k => 
  (k -> a -> Maybe a) -> k -> Map k a -> (Maybe a, Map k a)

lookupDelete k = do
  (ret, m) <- gets $ updateLookupWithKey (\_ _ -> Nothing) k
  put m
  pure ret
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple implementation is in terms of [`alterF`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v:alterF):

```
lookupDelete :: Ord k => k -> State (Map k v) (Maybe v)
lookupDelete = state . alterF (\x -> (x, Nothing))
```

The `x` in `alterF`'s argument is the `Maybe` value stored at the key given to `lookupDelete`. This anonymous function returns a `(Maybe v, Maybe v)`. `(,) (Maybe v)` is a functor, and basically it serves as a "context" through which we can save whatever data we want from `x`. In this case we just save the whole `x`. The `Nothing` in the right element specifies that we want deletion. Once fully applied, `alterF` then gives us `(Maybe v, Map k v)`, where the context (left element) is whatever we saved in the anonymous function and the right element is the mutated map. Then we wrap this stateful operation in `state`.

`alterF` is quite powerful: lots of operations can be built out of it simply by choosing the correct "context" functor. E.g. `insert` and `delete` come from using `Identity`, and `lookup` comes from using `Const (Maybe v)`. A specialized function for `lookupDelete` is not necessary when we have `alterF`. One way to understand why `alterF` is so powerful is to recognize its type:

```
flip alterF k :: Functor f => (Maybe a -> f (Maybe a)) -> Map k a -> f (Map k a)
```

Things with types in this pattern

```
SomeClass f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

are called "optics" (when `SomeClass` is `Functor`, they're called "lenses"), and they represent how to "find" and "mutate" and "collate" "fields" inside "structures", because they let us focus on part of a structure, modify it (with the function argument), and save some information through a context (by letting us choose `f`). See the `lens` package for other uses of this pattern. (As the docs for `alterF` note, it's basically `at` from `lens`.)